# Edge Animations won't follow display: inline-block rule

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css

I'm a graphic designer weaning myself off Muse and into Dreamweaver, learning HTML, making my current client's site as my first non-Muse one (OK, fine, I'm starting with Bootstrap, but it'll get better!).

Here's the in-progress:
http://wearethefirehouse.com/livesitetest/

I need all those Edge animations to sit inline with one another, and 'tight'. They're all on different z-indexes, and if one bubbles up over another, one I'm fine with that.

```
    <div class="cover-container">
              <!-- Edge Animate Buttons-->
      <object id="demobutton" type="text/html" width="170" height="170" data-dw-widget="Edge" data="edgeanimate_assets/demo-button/Assets/demo-button.html"></object>
      <object id="demobutton" type="text/html" width="170" height="170" data-dw-widget="Edge" data="edgeanimate_assets/demo-button/Assets/demo-button.html"></object>
      <object id="demobutton" type="text/html" width="170" height="170" data-dw-widget="Edge" data="edgeanimate_assets/demo-button/Assets/demo-button.html"></object>
      <object id="demobutton" type="text/html" width="170" height="170" data-dw-widget="Edge" data="edgeanimate_assets/demo-button/Assets/demo-button.html"></object>
      <object id="demobutton" type="text/html" width="170" height="170" data-dw-widget="Edge" data="edgeanimate_assets/demo-button/Assets/demo-button.html"></object>
      <object id="demobutton" type="text/html" width="170" height="170" data-dw-widget="Edge" data="edgeanimate_assets/demo-button/Assets/demo-button.html"></object>
      <object id="demobutton" type="text/html" width="170" height="170" data-dw-widget="Edge" data="edgeanimate_assets/demo-button/Assets/demo-button.html"></object>
    </div>
```

I tried:

```
#demobutton {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

and

```
#demobutton {
    display: inline;
}
```

No dice.
Also, I need to make them all links... tried on the first one and I'm getting nothing. I'm sure its something simple.

Here's a jsFiddle, please tear apart any inefficiencies in the code while you're at it!
http://jsfiddle.net/8SaL3/

Comment: You will get better answers if you provide a small self-contained example, which contains just enough code to demonstrate the problem, without anything extra. Post this code into the question, AND in a JSFiddle (jsfiddle.net). Doing this can be a lot of work, but it's a critical part of the process of troubleshooting your problem.

Comment: Wow. how embarrassing. I was applying the display style rules to the individual buttons, not the enclosing container. oops.

Can anyone help me with the linkable part though? tried the obvious route of putting the object code where text would go in a regular link, got nothing.